# calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} {\frac{\binom{n^2-n}{n}}{\binom{n^2}{n}}}$

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients

I'm working on a problem and that expression came up. (Actually, I need to show that it's less than 1/2 to n >3,  but this limit left me very intrigued). When plotting, I saw that the value comes very close to 1/e as n grow, but I can't show it. I tried to use inequality   $\left(\frac{n}{ k}\right)^k \leq {n \choose k} \leq \left(\frac{en}{ k}\right)^k$, but I can't get anywhere. Can anybody help me ?

[plot of sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQkFm.png)

Comment: Numerical analysis indicates that the limit is $\frac{1}{e}$. I think, with the Stirling approximation, this can be proven.

Comment: Yes, just use Stirling's approximation and the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - 1/n)^n = 1/e$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have $$a_n:={{n^2-n\choose n}\over {n^2\choose n}}=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{n^2-n-k\over n^2-k}=\prod_{k=0}^n \left (1 -{n\over n^2-k}\right ) $$
Next
$$ 1- {1\over n-1}=1-{n\over n^2-n}\le 1-{n\over n^2-k} \le 1-{1\over n}$$
Hence $$\left (1-{1\over n-1}\right )^n\le a_n \le  \left (1-{1\over n}\right )^n $$
Therefore $\lim a_n=e^{-1}.$

**Remark** Stirling's formula is not needed here. Just the definitions of $e$ and the binomial coefficients.

Comment: beautiful demonstration !! thanks